# Unity5.6 Rolling world

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, rotation

I hope you guys could help me with my new game. I want to have a miniature world (a simple sphere) which will rotate (just like a rolling ball) when the player moves. But to be honest I have no idea how to make the world (sphere) rotate.

Comment: We typically like to see the code that you've tried so far here on Stack Overflow.  You can try the [Game Design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) SE site, but you may want to check how to ask questions on that site first.  I know Unity questions are popular there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually normally done by building your world flat - allowing you to easily use the rigidbody/physics logic that you're accustomed to.

Then, you can create the "rolling world" look by applying a shader over it. One such popular shader on the asset store is ["Curved World"](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/26165).

Creating an actual traversable area across a sphere can be quite difficult, due to needing to adjust the world gravity to ensure your player doesn't fall off the side etc.

Comment: thanks a lot. I found the asset and everything works :)